# Problem regarding phase difference in Transmission lines

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electrical-engineering

In order to find **impedence** variation in **Transmission line(T.L.)** we usually draw **Smith chart**(it is a complex reflection coefficient ($\Gamma$) plane on which constant resistance and reactance circles are superimposed because they have one to one mapping)

**Question:** In Smith chart,

on The VSWR (voltage standing wave ratio) circle ,the phasor$\left(\Gamma_{L}=|\Gamma_{L}|e^{i{\theta_{\Gamma}-2\beta l}}\right)$ moves by $2\pi$ radians in A.C.W direction ,when we move $\dfrac{\lambda}{2}$ distance from load end towards generator (source) end on T.L.

But in my wave lessons i have learned that path difference of $\dfrac{\lambda}{2}$ corresponds to the rotation of phasor by $\pi$ radians so, **why here in T.L. we have an anomaly**(i want physical description )

**symbols used**

$\beta= $phase constant;

$|\Gamma_{L}|=$magnitude of reflection coefficient at load end (due to mismatching)

$l$ is length of transmission line

Comment: The distance between nodes in a standing wave is half a wavelength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reflection coefficient plotted on the Smith chart is the ratio between an incident wave phasor and reflected wave phasor, in a fixed reference plane (say the connector flange of a network analyzer). If you move the load a distance λ/2 away from the reference plane, then both the incident wave and the reflected wave need to travel this extra λ/2 (to and from the load respectively). This simply adds up to the total extra path length λ, corresponding to 2π radians, as you would expect.